# Ggplot - how to change colour scale of plot for ratio type of data

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a graph where x is one value, y is second value and I also want to add ratio to this plot which is x/y

`ggplot(data, aes(x=value1, y=value,col=ratio)) + geom_text(label=head(data$name),size=4, angle=45)+ ggtitle("Value x vs value y")`

I want to make this easier to read so I'm trying to change colour of ratio but as a result of adding `scale_colour_brewer(guide = "colourbar")`I'm receiving `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. My guess is i picked wrong scale function but I can't find which would be right for this type of graph.

Comment: You can either categorize your ratio in a meaninful/useful number of categories, and use scale_colour_brewer. Or you can use something like scale_color_gradient if you want to keep the ratio continuous.

Comment: Scale_color_gradient works! Thanks